# The short script doesn't work at Chrome but work at Firefox.

Tags: php, javascript

This is a js script checkbox to select all dates. It works at Firefox but not at Chrome.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
function toggle(source) {
      checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('check_time[]');
      for each(var checkbox in checkboxes)
        checkbox.checked = source.checked;
    }
</script>

<?php
session_start();
include ("include/dbconnect.php");
$timestamp = mysql_real_escape_string(strtotime($_POST['date']));
$doc_username = $_SESSION['username'];
$date = @ strip_tags (date("Y-m-d",$timestamp));

$timezone ="Asia/Kuala_Lumpur";
if(function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')) date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
    $todaydate = date("Y-m-d");

if($date == '')
{
  echo "<i>Please select a date</i>";
}else if ($date < $todaydate)
{   
  echo "<i>* You are not allowed to choose date before $todaydate</i>";

}else
{
$inc   = 1800;
$start = (strtotime('0830')); // 9 AM
$end   = (strtotime('1630')); // 5 PM
echo "<b>*Pick if the time is not available</b><br> <br>";
echo "<form action='doc_confirmtime.php' method='POST'>";
echo "<input type='checkbox' onClick='toggle(this)' />Select All<br/>";
for( $i = $start; $i <= $end; $i += $inc )
{   
    $timeslot = date( 'G:i:s ', $i + $inc );// to the standart format
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * from appointment Limit 1");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $date2 = $row['date'];
        $time = $row['time'];

        $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT doc_username, date, time, status from appointment WHERE (doc_username = '$doc_username' AND date = '$date' AND time = '$timeslot') AND (status = '0' OR status = '1' OR status = '2' OR status is NULL)");
        $result = mysql_fetch_array($query2,0);

        if ($result > 0)
        {
            echo "<font size='+1' face='Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif'><input type='checkbox' name='check_time[]' value='$timeslot' checked = 'checked' DISABLED><b>$timeslot</b></font><br>";
        }else
        {
            echo "<font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif'><input type='checkbox' name='check_time[]' value='$timeslot'>$timeslot</font><br>";
        }


    }
}
echo "<i>*Highlighted Time has chosen by you or your patient</i>";
echo "<br><br>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' style='width:60px; height=30px' />";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='Date' value='$date' >";
echo "</form>";


}
mysql_close($connect);
?>
```

This is actually a php that run by a JQuery AJAX html page. When submit button is enter, a list of dates(Checkbox) and a "select all" checkbox is shown. Firefox definitely can work but not at Chrome.

Comment: Press F12 and check your Console for any output messages in Chrome.

Comment: wat error do u get in chrome ??

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Also tags like `font`,`b`..etc are alse depreciated..use `span`,`<strong>` instead

Comment: are you sure it's `for each`? i thought it should be `for(var checkbox in chekboxes)`

Comment: **are you really writing script first than start session ???** are not getting session error ??

Comment: OK, noted to NullPointer. No error I get from chrome. When I remove the script and run, it shows list of dates but my 'Select All' button doesn't work (because I removed the script already). So obviously there is a problem at the script there.

Comment: trun on E_WARNING in phpini

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, finally I got answer from this page. Here I share the source

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function toggle(source) {
   checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('check_time[]');
   for(var i in checkboxes)
      checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if for each() syntax work in other browsers rather than Firefox?

You should use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach to iterate over the elements.

I would also recommend using jQuery library as it eases work with Javascript when you don't know much about language it self.

In jQuery it would look like this:

```
function toggle(source) {
  $checkboxes = $('input[name=check_time]');
  $checkboxes.each(function(){
    $(this).attr("checked", source.checked);
  });
}
```

Comment: After import Jquery, but still cannot work for my select all button

Answer (score 0):

Your for each loop is still not supported by Chrome. Instead use a `for`:

```
for(var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++)
{
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
}
```

Chrome currently only supports Javascript 1.5 and the syntax you used is a feature of Javascript 1.6 ([which now looks to be deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in)). The reason for this is because the Chrome developers aim to keep Chrome inline with Safari (the other major webkit user).